# How to map data such that I can use it to generate pie chart?

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

I was wondering how can I map data of 2 arrays such that I can use the data to generate charts  using d3.js

Current I have 2 arrays:

```
wordsArray = {"THE","MAIN","PURPOSE","OF","PHOTOSYNTHESIS","IS","TO","MAKE",
             "FOOD","FOR","PLANT","IT","PRODUCE","SUGAR","MANUFACTURE"};
computationArray = {6,1,2,2,1,3,3,1,3,4,4,2,1,2,1};
```

The wordsArray contains all the distinct words and the computationArray contains the number of times each word appears.

I would like to know if there is any shortcut to make it look like this:

```
var data = [{"words":"THE", "count": "6"}, 
{"words":"MAIN", "count": "1"}, {"words":"PURPOSE", "count": "2"}, 
{"words":"OF", "count": "2"}.... ];
```

Thanks!

Comment: shortcut: write some code to transform this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [zip](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_zip) function in d3:

```js
d3.zip(wordsArray, computationArray).map(function(e) {
    return { words: e[0], count: e[1] };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

shortcut is called [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

npm install underscore

using that fine lib you can do:

```
var data = _.map(_.zip(wordsArray, computationArray), function(v){
   return {words: v[0], count: v[1]};
});
```